# How do you get the title 'moderator'?

Tags: support, moderators

Why do some people with a lot of reputation have a diamond and 'moderator' next to their name. If it is to do with the amount of reputation then how much reputation do you need?

Answer (score 7):

Moderator handle site administration and are elected.

Every time when new moderators are needed, an election takes place. [This is the result from the last election.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171547/spring-2013-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results)

Comment: Who are they elected by???

Comment: @user2568107 By us, the users.